# onChange function is running on infinite LOOP

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function that is calculating NetPrice after taking UnitPrice and Quantity from the user through input fields, and after that, it also calculates the total Netprice by taking the individuals NetPrices one by one. It is working fine, but the problem is that when it calculates the first NetPrice, it starts an infinite loop and keeps on printing and showing this NetPrice on console (because I have a console log on this Price just for double checkup). Why is it doing this?

One more thing, I have my code in `OnChange()` function and I am using **jQuery** and **Bootstrap**.

Here is my function:

```
function myFunction(c) {
    var unitPrice = $("#unitPrice" + c).val();
    var productQuantity = $("#productQuantity" + c).val();
    var result = productQuantity * unitPrice;
    $("#netPrice" + c).val(result);
    total += (result);
    console.log(total);
}
```

And below are the fields where I am calling this function:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="productQuantity0"
           class="productQuantity form-control"
           onchange="myFunction(0)" placeholder="Product Quantity"
           aria-label="quantity" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
</div>
```

And also in this field:

```
'<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<input type="number" id="productQuantity' + productCount +
    '"   name="productQuantity[]" class="productQuantity form-control" placeholder="Product Quantity"  onchange="myFunction(' +
    productCount + ')" aria-label="quantity" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">' +
'</div>' +
```

Comment: Provide a snippet that reproduces the issue, there might be an event listener on the 'netPrice' element

Comment: You'll need to provide a snippet that demonstrates the issue.  There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've provided (though the id+n it a bit of an awkward work around, it should still work).  Have a read of [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop default behavior of on change event of input.
You can add below line in your code

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="productQuantity0"
           class="productQuantity form-control"
           onchange="return myFunction(0)" placeholder="Product Quantity"
           aria-label="quantity" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
</div>
```

your JS code should be

```
function myFunction(c) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var unitPrice = $("#unitPrice" + c).val();
    var productQuantity = $("#productQuantity" + c).val();
    var result = productQuantity * unitPrice;
    $("#netPrice" + c).val(result);
    total += (result);
    console.log(total);
    return false;
}
```